# Export Cgridview (With Custom Columns) To Excel

Tags: php, yii

I have a CGridView which uses Active Records as well as functions defined in the model so as to make it a custom column. This works perfectly fine for CGridView.

But I do want to export the same data to the excel sheet.

I have tried **ExcelView** but it doesnot seem to support the below code.

**$data->getCallActions()** doesn't seem to be getting called.

EExcelView Code:

```
$this->widget('ext.eexcelview.EExcelView', array(
            'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
            'title'=>'Title',
            'autoWidth'=>false,
            'disablePaging'=>true,          
            'columns' => array(
                                    'id',
                                    'caller_number',
                                    array(
                                            'name'=>'Action',
                                            'type'=>'raw',
                                            'value'=>'$data->getCallActions()',
                                    ),
                                    'created_date',
                            )               
                    )
            );
```

Please do let me know if any other excel extensions can support this functionality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with `EExcelView` extension and this is not working, then you rather should ask this extension's author for what can be wrong.

However, I don't think, that using this or any other extension is required.

If you're displaying your data in a grid view, then you probably feed it using [`CActiveDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider/) (as in demo applications). Simply change it (in another action - i.e. in action, which you will use to export data to Excel, not the one that you use to render grid view) to use [`CArrayDataProvider`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider/). It will take your data from database, and give it to you as an array. You can then parse this array with simple  `foreach` iteration and you have access to every row, column and cell.

Next would be to write it in `.csv` format (that is -- separate rows with line breaks and cells with comma or tab), write such data as file and... you're done. Excel can import `.csv` file without any problems, if only it is correctly written.